# How to find Linux-Kernel Menuconfig Dependencies?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dependencies

I have to build the Linux Kernel and I am in the menuconfig.

I would like to include the following as Built-in and not a module:

```
Realtek RTL8152/RTL8153 Based USB Ethernet Adapters
```

The issue is that when I press Y to have it built-in, I get the message:

```
This feature depends on another which has been configured as a module.
As a result, this feature will be built as a module.
```

How can I know what the dependencies are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

I pressed on H for help, and there's this fied:

```
Depends on:
```

I feel dumb right now.